# Cutting selection with CUA-mode bindings after searching

Tags: key-bindings, mark, cua-mode

I want to cut/copy some code with this method:

- setting a mark with <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>,
- searching with <kbd>C-s</kbd>,
- then cutting/copying the selection.

Check the following image:

[image]

I can copy selected code with <kbd>M-w</kbd> or cut (kill) it with <kbd>S-Del</kbd>.

But since I am using CUA-mode, I would prefer to use its keybindings.
Copying with <kbd>C-c</kbd> works but cutting with <kbd>C-x</kbd> fails.
Is it possible to tweak <kbd>C-x</kbd> to make it work in this situation?

Comment: I don't see how even `M-w` or `S-<delete>` or `S-DEL` works. The current search hit is not in any way *selected* (as in the region). But if all you want to do is free up `C-x` during Isearch then this will do that: `(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-x") nil)`. That makes your normal binding of `C-x` usable. But it will not cut the highlighted search hit. It will cut the region from the mark to point (end of search hit, if forward).

Comment: Oh, I see that you mentioned `C-SPC` to mark. In that case, what I suggested should do what you want: **`(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-x") nil)`**.

Answer (score 1):

It seems @Drew already answered in the comments of the question.

This makes it:

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-x") nil)
```

He deserves the merit.
I just copy the solution here for better reading ;-)